# sklearn: Regression models on sparse data?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, sparse-matrix

Does python's scikit-learn have any regression models that work well with sparse data?

I was poking around and found [this](http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.sparse.LogisticRegression.html) "sparse linear regression" module, but it seems outdated. (It's so old that scikit-learn was called 'scikit**s**-learn' at the time, I think.)

Answer (score 5):

Most scikit-learn regression models (linear such as `Ridge`, `Lasso`, `ElasticNet` or non-linear, e.g. with `RandomForestRegressor`) support both dense and sparse input data recent versions of scikit-learn (0.16.0 is the latest stable version at the time of writing).

**Edit**: if you are unsure, check the docstring of the `fit` method of the class of interest.